# Question about $\sigma$-Algebra of measurable function

Tags: measure-theory

If I have a $\mathcal{A}-\mathcal{A}'$ measurable function

$$T : \Omega \to \Omega' $$ according to measurable spaces $(\Omega ,\mathcal{A})$ and $(\Omega' ,\mathcal{A}')$, and $B\subset \mathcal{A}'$, does then

$$ \sigma(T^{-1}(B))  = T^{-1}(\sigma(B))$$

hold?

I see that

$$ \sigma(T^{-1}(B))  \subset T^{-1}(\sigma(B))$$

but I do not see how to show the other inclusion.

Comment: Note that $T^{-1}(\sigma(A)) = T^{-1}(A) = \sigma(T^{-1}(A))$, where I added/removed $\sigma$s in cases where they are applied to sets that are already $\sigma$-algebras. BTW: the assumption $A\subset A'$ implies that also $\Omega \subset \Omega'$. Do you really want to assume that?

Comment: @PhoemueX maybe I should use different symbols, note that $A \neq \mathcal{A}$. Therefore $T^{-1}(\sigma(A)) \neq T^{-1}(A)$ in general.

Comment: Sorry, that was hard to see on my mobile phone (but still dumb of me). I hope my answer is helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define

$$\Gamma:=\{M\subset \Omega'\mid T^{-1}(M)\in \sigma(T^{-1}(B))\}$$

Show that this is a $\sigma$-algebra that contains $B$.